# Browser Extension - Open Background Page on browser_action

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

I want to create a browser extension, that simply opens the extensions background page, when I press on the extension's icon in the toolbar. The problem is, that when I add the browserAction listener to the toolbar icon in a script on the background page, it gets triggered again when I open the background page, so when I click the icon again, it opens 2 new tabs and so on...

**file tree:**
[click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9MuH.png)

**manifest.json**

```
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Easy Films",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Easy Films",
    "default_icon": "icons/browser_action.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "page": "background/index.html"
  }
}
```

**background/index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Content will be added</h1>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**background/script.js**

```
function onStartup() {
  browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(onClicked);
}

function onClicked() {
  browser.tabs.create({
    url: location.href
  });
}

browser.runtime.onStartup.addListener(onStartup);
```

Comment: Opening the background page in a visible page is a mistake. The background page is a special hidden page which runs invisibly so you should never duplicate it in a visible tab.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using start_url or scope?

"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Easy Films",

"version": "1.0",

"start_url": "/",

"scope": "/",

Comment: As I'm writing my extension to be usable in different browsers, the manifest needs to be in version 2, and version 2 doesn't support these manifest data.